# Results group cond mongodb push array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to reach this result after the internships:

```
dataset: [
 {
  seriesname: "GROUP 1",
   data: [
    {
     stage: 'START'
     value: 3
    },
    {
     stage: 'END'
     value: 4
    }
   ]
 },
 {
  seriesname: "GROUP 2",
  data: [
   {
    stage: 'START'
    value: 3
   },
   {
    stage: 'END'
    value: 1
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

However I can not perform a [cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) and [push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) together for multiple simultaneous results

```
{ $unwind: '$name' },
  { $group: {
    _id: '$name.name',
    data: { $push: {
      $first: {
        'value': { $sum: {
          $cond: [
            { $and: [
              { $eq: ['$stage', 'START'] },
              { $gte: ['$dStart', new Date(dStart)] },
              { $lte: ['$dEnd', new Date(dEnd)] }
            ] }, parseInt(1), parseInt(0)] } },
        'stage': 'START'
      },
      $first: {
        'value': { $sum: {
          $cond: [
            { $and: [
              { $eq: ['$two', 'END'] },
              { $gte: ['$dStart', new Date(dStart)] },
              { $lte: ['$dEnd', new Date(dEnd)] }
            ] }, parseInt(1), parseInt(0)] } },
        'stage': 'END'
      }
    }}
  } }
```

How could I work all these stages correctly?

- I checked some other posts, but I did not find any that worked with cond and push creating arrays

Comment: It would be helpful if you'll post some sample data too... not just code and desired result. Also, consider https://mongoplayground.net/ as a template for answers.

Comment: Basically it would be something like this, but with the date being array with more than object and more than one query https://mongoplayground.net/p/OjmSixJBfTG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break this into two stages, first group and calculate each value and then restructure the data as wanted like so:

```
{
  $group: {
      _id: "$name.name",
      start: { 
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            { $and: [
              { $eq: ['$stage', 'START'] },
              { $gte: ['$dStart', date_param_1] },
              { $lte: ['$dEnd', date_param_2] }
            ] }, 1, 0] 
        }
     },
     end: { 
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            { $and: [
              { $eq: ['$two', 'END'] },
              { $gte: ['$dStart', date_param_1] },
              { $lte: ['$dEnd', date_param_2] }
            ] }, 1, 0] 
        }
     }
  }
},
{
  $addFields: {
     data: [{value: "$start", stage: "START}, {value: "$end, stage: "END"}]
  }
}
```